# Replacing specific substrings in a specific part of a string

Tags: python, regex, str-replace

I have a following text file that is to be edited in a certain manner. The part of the file that comes to inside the **(init:** part is to be overwritten and nothing except that should be edited.

File:

```
(define (problem bin-picking-doosra)

(:domain bin-picking-second)
;(:requirements :typing :negative-preconditions)
(:objects        
)
(:init 
        (batsmen first_batsman)
        (bowler none_bowler)
        (umpire third_umpire)
        (spectator no_spectator)
)

(:goal (and
                (batsmen first_batsman)
                (bowler last_bowler)
                (umpire third_umpire)
                (spectator full_spectator)
)
)
)
```

In this file I want replace every line that is inside the **(init:** section with the required string. In this case, I want to replace:

1. (batsmen first_batsman) with (batsmen none_batsmen)
2. (bowler none_bowler) with (bowler first_bowler)
3. (umpire third_umpire) with (umpire leg_umpire)
4. (spectator no_spectator) with (spectator empty_spectator)

The code I currently have the following:

```
file_path = "/home/mus/problem_turtlebot.pddl"
s = open(file_path).read()
s = s.replace('(batsmen first_batsman)', '(batsmen '+ predicate_batsmen + '_batsman)')
f = open(file_path, 'w')
f.write(s)
f.close()
```

The term **predicate_batsmen** here contains the word *none*. It works fine this way. This code only satisfies point number 1. mentioned above

There are three problems that I have.

1. This code also changes the '(batsmen first_batsmen)' part in **(goal:** part which I dont want. I only want it to change the **(init:** part
2. Currently for the other strings in the **(init:** part, I have to redo this code with different statement. For eg: for '(bowler none_bowler)' i.e. point number 2 above, I have to have a copy of the coded lines again which I think is a not a good coding technique. Any better way for it.
3. If we consider the first string in **(init:** that is to be overwritten i.e (batsmen first_batsman). Is there a way in python that no matter what matter what is written in the  question mark part of the string like (batsmen ??????_batsman) could be replaced with *none*. For now it is *'first'* but even if it is written *'second'*((batsmen second_batsman)) or *'last'* ((batsmen last_batsman)) , I want to replace it with *'none'*(batsmen none_batsman).

Any ideas on these issues?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to find the `init`-group. The `init`-group seems to have the structure:

```
(:init
    ...
)
```

where `...` is some recurrence of text contained inside parenthesis, e.g. `"(batsmen first_batsman)"`. Regular expressions is a powerful way to locate these kind of patterns in text. If you are not familiar with regular expressions (or regex for short) have a look [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp).

The following regex locates this group:

```py
import re

#Matches the items in the init-group:
item_regex = r"\([\w ]+\)\s+"
#Matches the init-group including items:
init_group_regex = re.compile(r"(\(:init\s+({})+\))".format(item_regex)) 

init_group = init_group_regex.search(s).group()
```

Now you have the `init`-group in `match`. The next step is to locate the term you would want to replace, and actually replace it. `re.sub` can do just that! First store the mappings in a dictionary:

```py
mappings = {'batsmen first_batsman': 'batsmen '+ predicate_batsmen + '_batsman',
'bowler none_bowler': 'bowler first_bowler',
'umpire third_umpire': 'umpire leg_umpire',
'spectator no_spectator': 'spectator empty_spectator'}
```

Finding the occurrences and replacing them by their corresponding value one-by-one:

```py
for key, val in mappings.items():
    init_group = re.sub(key, val, init_group)
```

Finally you can replace the `init`-group in the original string:

```py
s = init_group_regex.sub(init_group, s)
```

**This is really flexible!** You can use regex in `mappings` to have it match anything you like, including:

```py
mappings = {'batsmen \w+_batsman': '(batsmen '+ predicate_batsmen + '_batsman)'}
```

to match `'batsmen none_batsman'`, `'batsmen first_batsman'` etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer. Regex is a cool thing. Btw, what does the initialization 'fr' do . I use python 2.7 so not aware of this. Secondly, where do you use the match variable. It is having the important but not used in the code?

Comment: Oops, I changed the name of the `match` variable in the rest of the code. Edited. `fr` is a combination of the f-string-functionality and raw-string-functionality. If you're using 2.7 you can't use f-strings so I edited that part of the code.